# PHP File upload image not working

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a image in my db but it won't work.

here is the code to upload the image.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    mysqli_select_db("test", $con);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $no = $_POST['no'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE) {
            echo "Please select an image.";
        }

        else {
            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            // Check file size
            if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 500000) {
                echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }

            // Check if file already exists
            if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                echo "<p>Sorry, file already exists.</p>";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }

            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                echo "<p>Sorry, your file was not uploaded.</p>";
            }

            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            else {

                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                    $name = basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
                    $image = "uploads/".basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
                    echo "<p>".$name. " has been uploaded.</p>";
                    header("location: image.php");

                    $qry = "INSERT INTO images (id, name, image, username, password, dob, no) VALUES (NULL, '".$name."', '".$image."', '".$username."', '".$password."', '".$dob."', '".$no."')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $qry);

                    //$sql = "INSERT INTO images (username) VALUES ('$username')";
                    //$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                } 

                else {
                    echo "<p>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.</p>";
                }
            }
        }
     }
 ?>
```

it always said that sorry there was an error uploading the file.

and this is the error in the server log.

> PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpRGn6S7' to
>   'uploads/Screenshot from 2017-08-09 16-57-58.png' in
>   /var/www/html/practice1/images2.php on line 45, referer:
>   http://localhost/practice1/image.php

I am new to file uploading in PHP.
would really appreciate if someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any further details on the error it gave?  What is showing in the php/apache error logs? Is the filesize exceeding the php setting for max file upload size? Is the folder it's writing to, writeable by apache user?

Comment: can you describe what is issue you are facing?

Comment: do you have the `enctype` set in your html form? `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited to included the server log error.

Comment: yes @NorrisOduro

Comment: Problem is on the server. Maybe you haven't rights to write file in this folder, or folder doesn't exists. Is it running on Windows or Linux ?

Comment: I am using linux. The folder is located at var/www/html/practice1 and my upload directory is located at var/www/html/practice1/uploads

Comment: Let's chat about it. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153202/room-for-meloman-and-jayz-de-vera

Comment: @JayzdeVera `$target_dir = getcwd()."uploads".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows and Linux, the **move_uploaded_file() function doesn't work the same**. 
On Linux, you need to put the full path like this :

```
$target_dir = "/var/www/html/practice1/uploads/";
```

Or seperate project_dir and upload dir like this :

```
$project_dir = '/var/www/html/practice1/';
$target_dir  = $project_dir . 'uploads/';
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't knew about that cuz I shifted to linux and just a newbie in using it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
```

You'd rather use something like:

```
$target_dir = PROJECT_DIR . "uploads/";
```

With purpose to end-up with absolute path to uploads dir.

Comment: Do you really have this dir? Can you check it, just run command in terminal `ls /PROJECT_DIR/uploads`